# Repeater pulling as Null is code behind?

Tags: c#, sql, repeater

I have a repeater for Frequently asked questions on a Website that I'm trying to get separated into categories depending on which treeid it is related to.

When I reference the repeater (rp_FAQ) in the code behind to check if it is null so I can pass the category id to the stored procedure it keeps returning null when I need the item to exist when check that it's null.

I can't seem to find the route of the problem so as second set of eyes would be really grateful.

Thanks.

I have this repeater:

```
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rp_FAQ" DataSourceID="DS_GetFAQs" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rp_FAQCategories_ItemDataBound">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <div class="container-full fares_container">
                            <div class="row">
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <dt>Q: <%# Eval("Question") %></dt>
                        <dd>A: <%# Eval("Answer") %></dd>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </dl>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
    protected void rp_FAQCategories_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Repeater rp_FAQRep = e.Item.FindControl("rp_FAQ") as Repeater;

    if (rp_FAQRep != null)
    {

        if (TreeData.CurrentDefault.IsRelation(Convert.ToInt32(Resources.Pages.FAQ)))
        {
            DS_GetFAQs.SelectParameters["CategoryID"].DefaultValue = "1";
        }

        rp_FAQRep.DataSource = DS_GetFAQs;
        rp_FAQRep.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `rp_FAQ` inside another control? Why can't you reference it directly instead of using `FindControl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FindControl` method is only needed if you are trying to get a reference to a control which is inside the control which raised the event (in this case `ItemDataBound`). So you can either reference the control directly if it's not nested inside another control or use `sender`. For example:

```
var rp_FAQRep = rp_FAQ; //A bit pointless but demonstrates the point
```

or

```
var rp_FAQRep = (Repeater)sender;
```

Comment: I feel like a bit of a plonk now.

Yeah this was the issue. Trying to reference the control inside control.

Thanks for the answer. Really appreciate it! Great work!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to find the `rp_FAQ` control in a control *inside* `rp_FAQ` itself.

Since `e.Item` is the `RepeatItem` under `rp_FAQ`, you can just cast `e.Item.Parent`, or `sender` if you will.

Answer (score 1):

`e.Item` is the `RepeaterItem` within the `Repeater` - it does not contain the `Repeater` itself.  Just cast the `sender` of the event:

```
var rp_FAQRep = (Repeater)sender;
```